# Could I create plugin for IBM Watson bot using HTML and CSS to Integrate the bot to my website?

Tags: php, html, css, plugins, ibm-watson

I created a **web bot** for attending queries on my website using **IBM Watson**. My website is not a Wordpress website, so I cannot integrate the bot using the Wordpress plugins. So I am looking forward to **create a plugin** for the same. And the website is written in **HTML and CSS**. But all the codes I found on the IBM docs for Watson integration are in other languages(I have provided the links below). ***Can I get some help with the plugin creation codes in HTML and CSS and PHP***??

Documents version 1 and 2 of the IBM docs for **plugin creation** and **Integration**:

**Doc Version 1** - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1

**Doc Version 2** - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node

And I am running the **Lite plan** of IBM Watson which is enough for my website. And I do not want to go for the plus plan.